# Symfony2 + TinyMCE -> extreme textarea errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, symfony, tinymce-4

I'm currently using Symfony2 and a bootstrap template. I would like to use one of TinyMCE's extreme textarea for a newsletter, but I am running into issues while getting it to work.

Here's a link to the template where you can see the textareas : http://devoops.me/themes/devoops/#ajax/forms_layouts.html

It comes with a general js script. There is a start tinymce function :

```
function TinyMCEStart(elem, mode) {
    var plugins = [];
    if (mode == 'extreme') {
        plugins = ["advlist anchor autolink autoresize autosave bbcode charmap code contextmenu directionality ",
            "emoticons fullpage fullscreen hr image insertdatetime layer legacyoutput",
            "link lists media nonbreaking noneditable pagebreak paste preview print save searchreplace",
            "tabfocus table template textcolor visualblocks visualchars wordcount"];
    }
    <!-- ADDED BY ME
    tinyMCE.baseURL = 'http://'+location.host+resourcesUrl+"/plugins/tinymce";
    tinyMCE.baseURI.setPath(resourcesUrl+"/plugins/tinymce");
    tinyMCE.documentBaseURL = 'http://'+location.host+'/ormindo/web/';
    -->
    tinyMCE.init({selector: elem,
        theme: "modern",
        plugins: plugins,
        //content_css: "css/style.css",
        toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | print preview media fullpage | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
        style_formats: [
            {title: 'Header 2', block: 'h2', classes: 'page-header'},
            {title: 'Header 3', block: 'h3', classes: 'page-header'},
            {title: 'Header 4', block: 'h4', classes: 'page-header'},
            {title: 'Header 5', block: 'h5', classes: 'page-header'},
            {title: 'Header 6', block: 'h6', classes: 'page-header'},
            {title: 'Bold text', inline: 'b'},
            {title: 'Red text', inline: 'span', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
            {title: 'Red header', block: 'h1', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
            {title: 'Example 1', inline: 'span', classes: 'example1'},
            {title: 'Example 2', inline: 'span', classes: 'example2'},
            {title: 'Table styles'},
            {title: 'Table row 1', selector: 'tr', classes: 'tablerow1'}
        ]
    });
}
```

While fiddling with the template, I have come to the conclusion that this code :

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="wysiwig_full"></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    TinyMCEStart('#wysiwig_full', 'extreme');
});
</script>
```

is enough to get a textarea turned into a TinyMCE extreme text editor at any time.

The problem lies in getting this to work with a Symfony-generated form. I tried a first approach, not the prettiest but at least it does something (script is added with {% javascripts %}) :

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
// Create Wysiwig editor for textarea
TinyMCEStart('#ormindo_newsletterbundle_newslettermessage_contents', 'extreme');
});
```

This does work, alas only once. If I load another ajax content and come back, the textarea will be a standard one. Inspecting the page while doing so does not yield any javascript error.

Trying to break things down, I copy/pasted the raw html generated by Symfony (or should I say Twig) into the associated twig file.

I now had a twig file looking like this :

```
<div class="form-group">
<textarea id="ormindo_newsletterbundle_newslettermessage_contents" name="ormindo_newsletterbundle_newslettermessage[contents]" class="form-control"></textarea>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    TinyMCEStart('#ormindo_newsletterbundle_newslettermessage_contents', 'extreme');
});
</script>
```

This still did not work. However, removing the `<div class="form-group"></div>` tag made it work flawlessly. I have been trying several things, trying different TinyMCE version, hunting coding errors, to no avail.

Considering myself a web-dev novice, I fear this is the kind of error where I need an external point of view. Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Using the template's version of TinyMCE (4.0.16), I have a different error. The textarea is simply hidden, and my Inspect Element console shows "SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'" for theme.js once, then a lot of times for plugin.js (these are tinymce js files). I still am unable to beat this problem, and would really love a bit of guidance.

Comment: Alright, for 4.0.16 the issues seems to be that every .js file in TinyMCE is minified so it's xxx.min.js. However, TinyMCE keeps looking for xxx.js. I'm currently looking into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was absolutely unable to find the source of my issues. Being quite fed up, I switched up to CKeditor, and it worked flawlessly out of the box, I just had to change the editor path var because I have a folder containing all my plugins.

Answer (score 0):

How are you generating the symfony 2 form? 
As far as I know it is a simple matter to generate the tinymce, you just set an id/class for the form input that you wish to turn into a tiny mce, and then you set your javascript to look for that id/class and transform it.

To give a special id for a form field in symfony you do the following:

```
{{form_widget(form.text,{'id':'wysiwig_full'})}}
```

That will render a the field called text with the id wysiwig_full. Replace text with whatever the name of your field is.

Comment: So far I'm just using {{ form_widget(form.txt) }}, hence why I use something as long as "#ormindo_newsletterbundle_newslettermessage_contents" in TinyMCEStart : it is the id generated by Symfony. It does work, it just isn't pretty and your method is definitly what I should use. Sadly, both your method and mine yield the same result : should I change page and come back, the textarea will remain unchanged.

Comment: did you try different browsers? Also do you have any anything online I can see?

Comment: Chromium and Firefox display an identical behavior. I fear however all of my work is currently local-only.

Comment: you mentioned removing form-group makes it work flawlessly. I am also guessing you are using bootstrap.js? perhaps that is doing something that affects your code, try removing bootstrap.js or any other javascript affecting the form-group

Comment: Actually it seems to be the presence of a parent tag that disrupts everything. If I change the div class to anything else, I get the same result (also tried without bootstrap). If I remove the parent div, it works.